# Making a new file in subdirectories using python

Tags: python, file, output

I am trying to create a file in a subdirectory, both of which will not exist when the program is first run. When I do this:

```
newfile = open('abc.txt','w')
```

It will create abc.txt just fine but the following will cause an error, saying the file or directory does not exist

```
newfile = open('folder/abc.txt','w')
```

I tried using os.makedirs to create the directory first but that failed as well raising the same error. What is the best way to create both the folder and file?

Thanks

Comment: How did you use `os.makedirs`?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.makedirs('folder')
>>> newfile = open('folder' + os.sep + 'abc.txt', 'w')
>>> newfile.close()
>>> os.listdir('folder')
['abc.txt']
```

This works for me

Comment: did not know `os.sep`, will start using this.

Comment: yea. is os.sep just a seperator?

It works for me now. Thanks =)

Comment: `print(os.sep)` It varies depending on your operating system.  So it's '/' on real operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. `os.makedirs` takes just the path, not the file.  I assume you know this already, but you haven't shown your call to `makedirs` so I thought I'd mention it.
2. Consider passing an absolute, not a relative, path to `makedirs`.  Alternatively, use `os.chdir` first, to change to a directory in which you know you have write permission.

Hope those help!

Comment: It's `makedirs`, not `mkdirs`.  For just one directory it's `mkdir`

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path? From my understanding the path is hardcoded so if I move the entire directory of the file, everything would be in a mess?

Comment: Instead of `makedirs('folder')`, `makedirs('/path/to/folder')`.